# Search inside serialize data with MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'd like to search inside serialized array, data look like :

`a:7:{i:0;s:2:"34";i:1;s:1:"0";i:2;s:2:"42";i:3;s:2:"33";i:4;s:2:"48";i:5;s:2:"62";i:6;s:2:"47";}`

I tried this:

```
$id_serialize = '"'.$id.'"';
$req = requette("SELECT id FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%$id_serialize%'");
```

But it's not working, any solution?
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31151291/mysql-get-all-distinct-values-from-field-serialized-by-php/36129622#36129622

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is formatted a little wrong. If you are trying to pass `$id_serialize` to your query, it needs to be formatted like this:

```
$id_serialize = $id;
$req = requette("SELECT id FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%" . $id_serialize . "%'");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach  ($array as $item) $keys[]=md5(serialize($item));

$sql="insert into table set col='".serialize($array)."', `keys`='".implode(' ',$keys)."'";
```

...

```
$item=5;
$key=md5(serialize($item))
$sql="select id from table where MATCH (`keys`) AGAINST ('$key' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

...

field `keys` has FULLTEXT index

Answer (score 0):

You're building `$id_serialize`, but are using `$serialize` in the query string., so you're searching for `... LIKE '%%'`, most likely.

Comment: No sorry i just edit my code for post here, in my application i use the good one.