# Searching item in a serialized data field MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I use to store data in mysql just like that `"data1,data2,data3,data4"`

Then i decided to store them as serialized using php.
But the main problem that i faced is now i cannot search an item in that fields.

I was using FIND_IN_SET but i know that it doesn't work for serialized data.

My question is that should i turn back storing data with commas ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search inside serialize data with MYSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626114/search-inside-serialize-data-with-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to be searchable, you need it expressed as a series of rows that can be queried. If you need it to be in a comma separated format for performance reasons, that's another consideration. Sometimes you have to do both of these things and make sure your application keeps the two different forms in sync.

It is very hard to match the performance of a properly indexed table for matching queries when using serialized data, and likewise, the speed of retrieval for serialized data versus having to join in the other results. It's a trade-off.

Comment: it's essentially impossible to match speeds on properly normalized and indexed data vs. full table scan