# Mysql: get all distinct values from field serialized by PHP

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, yii2

I have a `movies` table (has data from a legacy project) with the field `genre` which contains values serialized by PHP like:

> a:3:{i:0;s:9:"Animation";i:1;s:9:"Adventure";i:2;s:5:"Drama";}

I'm working in a search page, & I need to find all unique genres of the current search result to be used as a filter in the page,

as an example, if the search result was these 2 movies:

- The Dark Knight (action, crime, drama)
- Black Knight (fantasy, adventure, comedy)

I want to know the combination of there genres, which will be:

```
['action', 'crime', 'drama', 'fantasy', 'adventure', 'comedy']
```

how to get the genres array? (I'm using [Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/)).

Comment: unserlise, combine, array_unique

Comment: Wouldn't it be a performance killer for large results?

Comment: if you cared about performance you would normalise your db

Comment: @Dagon as I mentioned in the question, it is a new project but on a legacy database :)

Comment: wellllll then that's the comprise you have chosen to live with

Comment: ....or do a one-time conversion of the legacy data....

Comment: If it's such a performance hit, you could paginate the results so you're not doing every line every time.

Comment: @BrianCohan I'm already paginating the data for showing it, but I still need the total genre array to help the user filter his whole search result, not just the 5 results showed in current offset.

Comment: you choose not to fix a broken db design, every action will be slower than if you did choose to fix it; don't complain that our solutions are slow- its  your decision to keep working with a poor db design

Comment: @Dagon I'm not "complaining"!, I'm just trying to reach the possible solution out there, every solution will has some drawbacks, I'm trying to list all of them to reach the best one. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) your data

```
$data = 'a:3:{i:0;s:9:"Animation";i:1;s:9:"Adventure";i:2;s:5:"Drama";}';
$data = unserialize($data);
print_r($data);
```

and you will get

```
Array
(
    [0] => Animation
    [1] => Adventure
    [2] => Drama
)
```

If you need to search the entire table for "Drama" to decide which shows/movies to display, you could always use wildcards in your search

```
select * from table where column like '%Drama%'
```

but of course make sure to take appropriate database precautions.

Comment: But I think fetching all results & looping on them to unserialize would be a bad performance hit! specially with large results.

Comment: I don't have the total number of rows right now, but it is meant to be something like imdb & stuff like that, & processing will depend on the user's search criteria.

Comment: But how many results will there be per search? In your example you have 2 - the records for Dark Knight and Black Knight . For that amount (or ten-ten-fold for that matter) it might not hurt to do it "within" php. But it will hurt if you want a query like "How many movies are tagged 'fantasy' and 'adventure' and 'comedy'.

Comment: @VolkerK unfortunately, user can search by genre

Comment: @BrianCohan I didn't mention it, but I already intend to query the genres exactly like the way you mentioned, that is why I voted up :)

Comment: Then do the conversion or live with the performance impact ( LIKE %xyz% -> no index will help -> you could use a flat file instead of the database). If you properly decouple the actual search mechanism in your php application you can do the switch at any time in the future (if and when the current layout hurts too much).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a serialize string that have various values in different position and you need to search from serialized field. You want particular key’s value using MySQL query. It is very easy with MySQL “%like%” statement but “%like%” fetches more matches which you do not require.
Search from serialized field: Suppose you have a following serialize string in database:

```
a:9:{s:2:"m1";s:4:"1217";s:2:"m2";s:8:"9986-961";s:2:"m3";s:19:"1988-03-07 00:00:00";s:2:"m4";s:0:"";s:2:"m5";s:0:"";s:2:"m6";s:0:"";s:2:"m7";s:3:"104";s:2:"m8";s:6:"150000";s :2:"m9";s:18:"Ok Then, Yes It Is";}
```

And you need the row in which the m9 value is ‘Yes It Is’.

So the sql will be like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '.*"array_key";s:[0-9]+:".array_value.".*'
```

test code

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '.*"m9";s:[0-9]+:".Ok Then, Yes It Is.".*'
```